# Replace 'nnn0n' with 'nnn1n' in Python using regular expressions

Tags: python, regex

I would like to replace a string in form `'nnn0n'` with the string in form `'nnn1n'` where `n` is any digit. What the easiest way to do that? So, far I tried the following:

```
int(re.sub(r'^(\d+?)(0)(\d)$', r'\1???\3', '7001'))
```

But what ever I insert in place of `'???'` either just `1` or `\1` returns incorrect result.

Any ideas?

**EDIT**:

I have come up with an ugly version:

```
re.sub(r'a1a', '1', re.sub(r'^(\d+?)(0)(\d)$', r'\1a1a\3', '7001'))
```

Anything nicer?

Comment: Is it always 3 digits, 1 digit to be replaced, 1 digit?

Comment: No it can be a differnt number of digits in the begining

Comment: And I want to replace second 0 from the end with 1

Comment: Any reason to avoid numerical methods? Like adding 10?

Comment: The only reason is that if 10 was aleady added, but you are right, it should be much simpler with numerical methods :).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do something like:

```
re.sub(r'^(\d{3})0(\d)$', r'\g<1>1\2', '7001')
```

Or if it's not always three numbers before the 0 you want to replace:

```
re.sub(r'^(\d+)0(\d)$', r'\g<1>1\2', '1234509')
```

**Edit** If you know that the number will always be of the same format, you can just use:

```
re.sub(r'0(?=\d$)', '1', '7001')
```

Answer (score 3):

You don't really need regexes.

```
replace = lambda x: '{0}1{1}'.format(x[:-2], x[-1]) if x[-2] == '0' else x
# or: x[:-2] + '1' + x[-1]
print replace('12345678901')
```

Comment: Yeah, but regex is more fun ;)

Answer (score 1):

You could use a named group to get around this

```
int(re.sub(r'^(?P<prefix>\d+?)0(\d)$', r'\g<prefix>1\2', '7001'))
```

But the most natural approach would probably be

```
int(re.sub(r'0(\d)$', r'1\1', '7001'))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> r = re.compile(r'(\d{3})0(\d)')
>>> r.sub('\g<1>1\g<2>', '88808')
88818
```

Answer (score 1):

Another one 'not brilliant' solution without regex - but i have to try it for myself atleast:

```
data = ['7001', '700001', '701', '71', '12345']
res = (int(x)+10 if len(x) > 2 and x[-2] == '0' else int(x) for x in a )
print list(res)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a numeric solution:

```
def addTenNumeric(n):
  """Add 10 to n if, as decimal, the 2nd least significant digit of n is 0"""
  if (n % 100) < 10:
    return n + 10
  return n
```

This ought to be a lot quicker than using regular expressions on string representations.